# Assistance writing an exponential decay formula

Tags: math, formula, exponential

I'm trying to write a decay formula, which is based on the ratio between x and y, assuming always that y > x.  The formula needs to have a lower limit of 0.25, and an upper limit of 1.0.

As the ratio between the two numbers decreases, the formula gets closers to 1, as the ratio increases, the formula gets closer to 0.25. The result of the formula is being used as a scalar.

If possible, I'd also like to toggle the rate at which the scalar approaches its limits.

Any guidance is much appreciated, as I'm ripping my hair out right now!

Comment: so you want a function that has as image [0.25, 1] and as domain [0, +inf and ] with `lm n->0 f=0.25` and `lm n->+inf f=1` where `n=x/y`? but with which kind of "graph"? logarithmic or what?

Comment: That's correct. x and y can be any number greater than 0. The limit of the output needs to be between 0.25 and 1, based on the ratio between x and y. If this function also has a "speed" toggle, for which the rate increases or decreases, that would be even better!

Comment: ok, please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example:
take in account `-1/x` with `x = [0, +inf]` then it has `f(x) = [-inf, 0]`.  so now let's take in account `1-1/x` with `x = [0, +inf]` it has `f(x) = [-inf, 1]`, but `f(x)=0 <=> x=1`.
So now we move the function 1 to the left, so we get `f(x) = 1-(1/(x+1))`.

now we need to map it in `[0.25, 1]`, so we do the same thing, but instead of `1` we use `0.75`, and we get

```
f(x) = 3/4 - 1/[x + (4/3)]
```

that has a domain of [0,+inf], `f(x)=0 <=> x=0` and an image of `[0,0.75]`, so now we are missing only the offset of `0.25`, with which, we get

```
f(x) =  3/4 - 1/[x + (4/3)] + 1/4
```

and if we sum up the pieces we get

```
f(x) = 1 - 1/[x + (4/3)] + 1/4
```

so now we have the right function, we just need to figure out what to put as `x`

we want  that when `x/y = 1 => 0 (to have f(0)= 0.25)` and `x/y = 0 => +inf (to have f(+inf)= 1)`, and we achieve that using `(y/x)-1`

At the end we get:

```
f(x,y) = 1 - 1/[((y/x)-1) + (4/3)] + 1/4
```

To manipulate the velocity, put the coefficient in front of the "old", with which you get:

```
f(x,y) = 1 - 1/[velocity*((y/x)-1) + (4/3)] + 1/4
```

Comment: This is great, thank you!!

atan(36/36)*(2/PI)*(3/4)+0.25 gives a maximum of 0.625. Changing 3/4 to 6/4 seems to fix it, I'm not sure why though.

Would you mind formulating this without the arctan? I don't have the arctan function available to me (my libraries are limited on this VM..), i'd also like to get a better grasp of it.

Comment: @MichaelFletcher please check the answer, i'm not too sure about the last phase, so please check it out and let me know

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. It's coming together.. I just need to figure out how to factor the velocity at which the decay happens now.

Comment: @MichaelFletcher added